# Wordpress Sub-menu

Tags: wordpress

At least, the lastest version of Wordpress includes submenu features, reflected in the NAVBAR. However, I was wondering how to display those submenus inside a children page, **highlighting** the active page.

Must I use a widget plugin?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to generate your menu.

A quick demo can be found on this site [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770884/how-to-display-part-of-a-menu-tree/7713875#7713875)

After you've done that, you'll need to add to your `CSS` to show the highlighted active page. This is a very simple little class that the `wp_nav_menu()` add's on when generating the page.

The `CSS` is `.current-menu-item` and you just need to add your attributes to it. Example below.

```
.current-menu-item {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This should be able to get you where you need without using a widget.

Comment: Oh I should read that demo again, it isn't so easy for me. So in that case I should make a sidebar template?

Comment: You can do it any way you want. have an if statement for the page level (how many parents), a sidebar template. a completely different page template which uses it. Whatever works best for you really